# The label does not denote a loop in forEach

Tags: android, kotlin

I am continuing from a loop in Kotlin but I get the warning from the studio that the label does not denote a loop. Could someone tell me what's wrong in the syntax?

Here is the code segment

```
 newRooms.forEach roomloop@ { wallRoom: WallRoom ->

          val index =  rooms.indexOf(wallRoom)

            if(index!=-1)
            {
                val room = rooms[index] //get the corresponding room.
                //check if the last session is same in the room.
                if(wallRoom.topics.last().fetchSessions().last()==room.topics.last().fetchSessions().last())
                {
                   continue@roomloop
                }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The labeled lambda expression here is a function literal, not a loop.

You cannot `break` or `continue` the lambda expression here because it is independent from the for-loop.

```
public inline fun <T> Array<out T>.forEach(action: (T) -> Unit): Unit {
    for (element in this) action(element)
}
```

You may use `return` to return from the function.

```
return@roomloop
```

Note that the code segments below behave the same as the other one, both of them will print `123`:

```
arrayOf(1, 2, 3).forEach label@ {
    print(it)
    return@label
}

label@ for (i in arrayOf(1, 2, 3)) {
    print(i)
    continue@label
}
```

Comment: Why it doesn't print just 1, shouldn't it exit because of return@label?

Comment: @AVEbrahimi It returns from the lambda only but will not break the for loop.